# Smart Contract working perfectly fine on remix but I face issues when I deploy it on the Binance Test Net

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, binance-smart-chain

I made a smart contract that allows user to enter pools and place a bet. When the pool time ends the users are given rewards given that they their bet turned out to be correct. When I tested this smart contract on remix everything is working perfectly fine. However, when I deployed this contract on the Binance test net and call the function through my front end, upon ending the pool all participants are returned the amount they contributed irrespective of whether they placed the correct bets or not.

Let's say for example 2 players join the pool by contributing 2 PRC tokens each. Player 1 places a bet that the price will be long where as Player 2 says the price will be short. Assuming the price ends up being long. Player 1 should be returned a total of 4 PRC tokens and Player 2 should get nothing. This is working perfectly on remix but upon deployment and integration with my front end upon ending the pool both the players are getting the amount they contributed regardless of the accuracy of their bets.

Here is my solidity code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract PrcToken is ERC20 {
    address private _owner;
    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    mapping(address => uint256) private _lastClaimTime;
    uint256 private constant _claimInterval = 2 hours;

    constructor() ERC20("PRC Token", "PRC") {
        _owner = msg.sender;
        _totalSupply = 100000 * 10**decimals();
        _mint(address(this), _totalSupply);
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == _owner, "Only the contract owner can call this function.");
        _;
    }

    function claimTokens(address recipient) external {
        require(_lastClaimTime[recipient] + _claimInterval <= block.timestamp, "Tokens can only be claimed once every 2 hours.");
        require(balanceOf(address(this)) >= 25, "Insufficient tokens in contract balance.");

        _lastClaimTime[recipient] = block.timestamp;
        _transfer(address(this), recipient, 25);
    }

    function getContractBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    struct Pool {
        uint256 startTime;
        uint256 endTime;
        uint256 totalAmount;
        mapping(address => uint256) participantAmounts;
        mapping(address => bool) participantBets;
        address[] participants;
        bool finalized;
    }

    Pool private _currentPool;

    function startPool(uint256 poolDuration) external onlyOwner {
        require(_currentPool.startTime == 0, "A pool is already active.");

        _currentPool.startTime = block.timestamp;
        _currentPool.endTime = block.timestamp + poolDuration;
        _currentPool.finalized = false;
    }

    function alreadyEnteredPool() private view returns (bool) {
        bool check=true;
        
         for(uint256 i=0; i < _currentPool.participants.length; i++){
            if (_currentPool.participants[i]==msg.sender)
            {
                check=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return check;
    }

    function enterPool(bool betLong, uint256 amount) external {
        require(_currentPool.startTime != 0, "No active pool available.");
        require(block.timestamp < _currentPool.endTime, "Pool entry closed.");
        require(amount > 0, "Invalid amount.");

        require(alreadyEnteredPool(),"You have already enterd the pool.");

        // Transfer required amount of PRC tokens from the participant to the pool
        require(transfer(_owner, amount), "Failed to transfer tokens.");


        // Store the participant's amount and bet
        _currentPool.participantAmounts[msg.sender] = amount;
        _currentPool.participantBets[msg.sender] = betLong;
        _currentPool.participants.push(msg.sender);
        _currentPool.totalAmount += amount;
    }

    function winCalculator(uint256 totalWinningAmount, uint256 totalWinnerContribution,uint256 participantAmount) private pure returns (uint256)
    {
        uint256 winning = (participantAmount*totalWinningAmount)/totalWinnerContribution;
        return winning;
    }

    function endPool(uint256 currentPrice, uint256 originalPrice) external onlyOwner {
    require(_currentPool.startTime != 0, "No active pool available.");
    require(block.timestamp >= _currentPool.endTime, "Pool still active.");
    require(!_currentPool.finalized, "Pool already finalized.");

    _currentPool.finalized = true;

    uint256 totalPrizePool = 0;
    uint256 totalWinnerContribution = 0;

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _currentPool.participants.length; i++) {
        address participant = _currentPool.participants[i];
        uint256 participantAmount = _currentPool.participantAmounts[participant];
        bool participantBetLong = _currentPool.participantBets[participant];

        bool isWinner;
        if (participantBetLong && currentPrice > originalPrice) {
            isWinner = true;
        } else if (!participantBetLong && currentPrice < originalPrice) {
            isWinner = true;
        }

        if (isWinner) {
            totalWinnerContribution += participantAmount;
        }

        totalPrizePool += participantAmount;
    }

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _currentPool.participants.length; i++) {
        address participant = _currentPool.participants[i];
        bool participantBetLong = _currentPool.participantBets[participant];
        uint256 participantAmount = _currentPool.participantAmounts[participant];

        if (participantBetLong && currentPrice > originalPrice && participantAmount > 0) {
            uint256 perWinnerAmount = winCalculator(totalPrizePool, totalWinnerContribution, participantAmount);
            require(transfer(participant, perWinnerAmount), "Failed to transfer winnings to participant.");
        } else if (!participantBetLong && currentPrice < originalPrice && participantAmount > 0) {
            uint256 perWinnerAmount = winCalculator(totalPrizePool, totalWinnerContribution, participantAmount);
            require(transfer(participant, perWinnerAmount), "Failed to transfer winnings to participant.");
        }
    }

    // Reset the pool for the next round
    delete _currentPool;
}

}
```